# Stderr and Stdout redirection to file doesn't save original line no from script

Tags: bash, debugging, scripting

I have script as

```
#!/bin/bash
exec 3>&1 4>&2
exec 1>/tmp/stdout.log
exec 2>/tmp/stderr.log
echo "This goes to /tmp/stdout.log"
echo "This goes to /tmp/stderr.log" 1>&2       
cmd1="$(uname -a)"
cmd2="$(uname +-a)"
exec 1>&3 2>&4
exec 3>&- 4>&-
```

when i open **stderr**
I get

```
This goes to /tmp/stderr.log
uname: extra operand `+-a'
Try `uname --help' for more information
```

Why is lineno, not appended with `stderr`? Is there a method where I can append fileno information to error file as well. Thanks.

Comment: Nothing writes line numbers automatically from shell scripts. What do you mean by `fileno`?

Comment: @Barmar `$LINENO`

Comment: If you want to write `$LINENO`, you have to do it explicitly. `echo $LINENO This goes to /tmp/stderr.log`. I'm not sure if there's a good way to put that on the variable assignment lines, though.

Comment: its not showing LINENO for `uname +-a` it just shows same LINENO where echo was done which is 12

Comment: Why would you expect it to show the LINENO for that? It will only show it when you echo it.

Comment: I want LINENO from the error command, this is what I desire.

Comment: I know you do. Like I said, there's nothing that does that automatically.

Comment: The `uname` command doesn't know what the line is in the script that's running it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really get automatic line numbers, but if you'd like some output to help get your bearings, you can use xtrace logging with a line number in `PS4`. This will interleave the log with the commands and line numbers being run:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec 3>&1 4>&2
exec 1>/tmp/stdout.log
exec 2>/tmp/stderr.log
PS4='+ (Line $LINENO) '
set -x
echo "This goes to /tmp/stdout.log"
echo "This goes to /tmp/stderr.log" 1>&2
cmd1="$(uname -a)"
cmd2="$(uname +-a)"
exec 1>&3 2>&4
exec 3>&- 4>&-
```

Here's the error log, showing executed commands and line numbers so you can more easily see where the `+-a` thing comes from:

```
+ (Line 7) echo 'This goes to /tmp/stdout.log'
+ (Line 8) echo 'This goes to /tmp/stderr.log'
This goes to /tmp/stderr.log
++ (Line 9) uname -a
+ (Line 9) cmd1='Linux localhost 4.14.0-3-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.14.17-1 (2018-02-14) x86_64 GNU/Linux'
++ (Line 10) uname +-a
uname: extra operand ‘+-a’
Try 'uname --help' for more information.
+ (Line 10) cmd2=
+ (Line 11) exec
```

Comment: Great, is there a way I can turn off `set -x` as the commands e.g `uname -a` are not continuous as there are between many other logical statements. I don't want to crawl to entire length of script

Comment: @lazereyes `set +x` will turn it off and stop logging commands and line numbers